# conditional search and replace differently in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, identifier

**This content is in text.txt for testing, I am going to rewrite bundle identifier in pipeline.**

**Current Behavior:**

All PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER will be replaced to "abc" if execute this command.

`sed -i -e "s/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =.*/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = abc;/g" text.txt`

**Expectation:**

However, I would like to change PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER separately, Eg. from BundleA to BundleZ and from BundleB to BundleX etc. How can i use sed command to match regex and replace them with different values?

**Content in text.txt:**

```
  {
    2D02E40000B4A5E006451C7 /* Debug */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        buildSettings = {
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "BundleA";
        
        };
        name = Debug;
    };
    2D02E4981E0000006451C7 /* Release */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        buildSettings = {
            PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "BundleB";
        };
        name = Release;
    };
}
```

Comment: `... | sed '/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =/ { s/"BundleA"/"BundleZ"/;t; s/"BundleB"/"BundleX"/;t; ... }' | ...`

Comment: sed: 1: "/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIF ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Comment: sed derived from BSD demand newline after `t` command. eg. `sed -e '/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =/ { s/"BundleA"/"BundleZ"/;t' -e's/"BundleB"/"BundleX"/;t' -e '}'` I only used `t`for efficiency, it can be elided: `sed '/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =/{ s/"BundleA"/"BundleZ"/;s/"BundleB"/"BundleX"/; ... }'`